# Проверить попадает ли точка в заданную область

Tags: c++

Есть 2 действительных числа, x и y, которые вводятся с клавиатуры. Нужно проверить попадет ли точка в заданную область, область это рисунок. Если да, то выполняется одно уравнение, если нет, то другое. Нужно помочь с проверкой на то попадает точка или нет, немного не знаю как это сделать

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    void main()
    {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    float x, y, p;  char n;
m1: cout << "Ввкдите кординаты точек:";
    cout << "\n\t x=";  cin >> x;
    cout << "\t y=";    cin >> y;
    if (y >= 0 && x >= 0 && x*x + y * y <= 1 || y >= 0 && x <= 0 && x*x + y * y <= -1)
        p = sin(x);
    else p = x+2*y;
    cout << "\t p=" << p;
    cout << "\nПродолжить?: Y/N -> ";   cin >> n;
    if (n == 'Y') goto m1;
    else cout << "Конец\n";
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

[image: ![Координатная площадь]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sLTk.png)

Comment: Потрудитесь задать вопрос, сударь. Где на картинке `y <= 0`? При каких значениях `x` и `y` `x*x + y * y <= -1`?

Comment: Извиняюсь, нужно помочь с проверкой на то попадает точка или нет, немного не знаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну давайте подумаем... Ломаная линия - это график `y = |x|`, так что чтоб точка была выше - надо, чтоб выполнялось условие `y > |x|`. А чтоб было в заштрихованной области - нужно выполнение `y*y + x*x < 1` (пересечение круга и угла).

Вместе -

```
if (y > abs(x) && x*x+y*y < 1) ...
```

Примерно так.

Можно, чтоб не использовать функцию `abs`, записать неравенство как `y*y > x*x && y > 0`.

Знаки могут быть `<=` и `>=` - в зависимости от того, должны ли граничные точки учитываться как часть фигуры.

Comment: А не лучше ли `y > 0 && y*y > x*x` чтоб сразу отсеивать отрицательные значения, не считая? Сокращенными вычислениями `&&`?

Comment: @Mikhailo Ну, в принципе да... Но тогда можно еще и добавить сразу `y<=1`, `x<=0.70711` и `x >= - 0.70711` :)

Answer (score -1):

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double x = GetCoord("x"), y = GetCoord("y");
    Console.WriteLine(y >= x && x >= -1 && y <= 1 ? "Попадает" : "Не попадает");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
static double GetCoord(string name = null)
{
    Console.Write("Введите координату {0}: ", name ?? "\b");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    try
    {
        return double.Parse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    catch 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Неверный ввод!");
        return GetCoord(name);
    }
}
```

http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread976436.html